# How can I have something like a message variable for a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I am looking for a way to get and display a message variable using jQuery and javascript. This is my situation: I have a code for a popup, but I don't want to have to copy and paste it for every single situation, and I only want the message to change.

This is the code I have to make one popup work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open popup
 $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
 });
 
 //close popup
 $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
  if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
  }
 });
 //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
 $(document).keyup(function(event){
     if(event.which=='27'){
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
  background: #b6bece;
  border-radius: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #c5ccd8;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up</a>

<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this element?</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="#0">Yes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">No</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

In sort I need to somehow get the message to display depending on which popup button I click but without having to rewrite the jQuery and Html changing the classes of everything.

Thank you. Let me now if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: How many popups and where would you rather the message data be ... in the html or stored in javascript? Numerous ways to approach this

Answer (score 1):

Trigger this when on click:

```
   $('.cd-popup-container p').text('New Message');
```

Edit:

Html

```
         <div id="Delete1">Yes</div>
         <div id="Nothing">No</div>
```

Javascript

```
        $('#Delete1').click(function(){
        $('.cd-popup-container p').text('Message 1');
        });
```

Comment: But how would I get the message from to be different depending on which button I click.

Comment: If you dont want to make a function for each button id you can still use one unique function aimed to a class for all delete buttons ((($('.Delete').click(function(){  for example))) and then get the content based on the parent div id, but I consider that looping the loop unless you plan to have more than a hundred buttons.

Comment: What if I have a form: <form id="accept_employe" action="/accept_employe" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">, how can I change the action depending on what is click and change <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('accept_employe').submit();">Yes</a>, which is what I am using to submit the form.